# Add to cart one product with different size at once in product listing page magento 2.3

Tags: configurable-product, magento2.3.1, qty

I want my customers to add products with different size at once in the shop cart, is this possible ? can anyone help me ?
please see attached screenshot:
https://imghostr.com/F2QnsQgR

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is achieved by customization. 
I have mention Cart class to pass selected variant into the cart and save it.

```
class Cart extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_cart;
    protected $productRepository;
    protected $formKeyValidator;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator $formKeyValidator
    ) {

        $this->_cart = $cart;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->_formKeyValidator = $formKeyValidator;

        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        if (!$this->_formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('*/*/');
        }

        $qtys       = $this->getRequest()->getParam('qty');
        $childIds   = $this->getRequest()->getParam('child_ids');

        $productstoadd = array();
        foreach ($qtys as $parentId => $array) {
            if (is_array($array)) { //configurable products
                foreach ($array as $attributeId => $child) {
                    foreach ($child as $childId => $value) {
                        if ($value != 0) {
                            $productstoadd[$parentId][$attributeId][$childId] = $value;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // simple products

            }
        }

        foreach ($productstoadd as $productId => $data) {
            foreach ($data as $attributeId => $child) {
            foreach ($child as $childId => $qty) {
               //reload product
                $_product = $this->productFactory->create()->setStoreId($storeId)->load($productId);
                $options = array(
                    $attributeId => $childId,
                );

                $params = array(
                    'form_key' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('form_key'),
                    'product' => $productId,
                    'super_attribute' => $options,
                    'qty' => $qty,
                    'selected_configurable_option' => $childIds[$productId][$attributeId][$childId],
                );

                $this->_cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
            }
        }        }
        $this->_cart->save();
        return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('checkout/cart');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Kruti, which file I can add this code??

Comment: you have to create one custom module with form which passes required values like productids, quantity (as per controller values) and on "add to cart" button you need to call the controller which I have mention.

Comment: Can you guide me please in explain?